# Hadoop/Hbase: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration

Tags: maven, hadoop, hbase

I have hadoop and Hbase installed, both working fine as far as I can tell. When trying to the built jar with hadoop, I get a

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
```

error, using Hbase version 0.90.2 in my maven dependency.

I think this is quite an old version of Hbase and I am unsure if this old version is compatible with hadoop 2.7.2 or even Java 8. Thus I tried using Hbase version 0.99.2 in my maven dependency, but then I get a

```
Failed to execute goal on project exercise_2: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company.exercise_2:exercise_2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:0.99.2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository
```

error from the maven plugin. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.99.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is jar caching issue, I think HbaseConfiguration is common class regardless of which version of hbase used.

Can you manually delete local repository file of hbase and try mvn XXXX  command once again.

Maven will then try to download and fix the class path.

for cross checking, use mvn ... -X option to see which version of jar its trying to download.

Since scope of this jar is

> provided

Cross check the hbase version of this jar in your cluster. by using ***"`hbase classpath`"*** and  check whether this jar version is closely matching with your jar file version of maven repository of your pom.xml.

That should fix.

Comment: Thank you for answering. How do I "manually delete the local repository file"?

Comment: maven has local repo in your local machine like .m2/repo

Comment: I am using IntelliJ with the maven plugin, I could not find any local maven repo in Intellij's files. Is there any way to do this, although I use the plugin?

Comment: I don't know about intelli j. you have to search for maven repository in your file system which is having all jars. Even though you are using any plugin it will store in local file system.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and the error wasn't fixed. Also i have encountered that following the link: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase/1.2.1/hbase-1.2.1.jar one receives an error 404. This is true also for every version of hbase > 0.94.9 (check http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/hbase/hbase/ for conforming that). Is there any other way to download hbase 1.2.1? I don't think older versions support Java 8.

Comment: Have you used same version of jar (group id , artifact id, version ) in your pom.xml, which is also present in your cluster  (I mean in ``hbase classpath`` )?

Comment: Looks like someone made a mistake while publishing hbase-1.2.1 artifacts to maven!..  some other version you need to try to fix this. That version should closely match your cluster hbase version